# Oracle - Materialized View, can this MV be fast refreshable?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, materialized-views

I have a materialized view that looks somewhat like the following and I'm wondering if there is anyway to have this materialized view 'fast' refreshable?  Basically, I'm asking the following:

1. Can a materialized view contain oracle functions such as COALESCE, NVL, NVL2, etc and still be fast refreshable
2. Can a materialized view contain functions that I have made and still be fast refreshable.
3. Can a materialized view contain joins to derived tables and still be fast refreshable?

I checked the [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/basicmv.htm#sthref537) about this, and it did not list these restrictions, however after testing the case below on my own system, I don't *believe* it is possible.

Oracle version: 10g

```
SELECT COALESCE (col1, col2),
       myOracleFunction(col3, col4)
  FROM tableA a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT   id, MAX (sample_key) prim_sam_key
            FROM table_sample
        GROUP BY id
          HAVING COUNT (1) = 1) b ON a.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requirements from the [link you provided](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/basicmv.htm#sthref537) that you're missing:

> - COUNT(*) must be specified.
> - The SELECT list must contain all GROUP BY columns.

Also, the following requirement indicates that, for your query, a fast refresh will only be possible if `table_sample` has been updated, but `tableA` has not:

> - Materialized aggregate views with outer joins are fast refreshable
>     after conventional DML and direct loads, provided only the outer table
>     has been modified. Also, unique constraints must exist on the join
>     columns of the inner join table. If there are outer joins, all the
>     joins must be connected by ANDs and must use the equality (=)
>     operator.

Finally, when asking about materialized views, it is always a good idea  to state exactly what materialized view logs you have created.